# Qt: Visibility state of the QWidget when used stylesheet

Tags: qt, stylesheet, visibility

I have customized QWidget named "MainWidget" and a customized QWidget named "ChildWidget".
MainWidget is the parent of ChildWidget and these child widgets are created dynamically and inserted into the MainWidget's stack of widgets.

I have used style sheet to set the background color of the both MainWidget and ChildWidget in their respective .ui (form) file. 
Select the widget ->Right Click on Widget-> Change stylesheet -> select background color-> apply -> save the .ui file

"background-color: ;"

Each ChidlWidget has its own unique size (width & height) such that when they have stacked on MainWidget's stack of widgets, there may be chances of one widget overlapping other widget, some widgets are completely obscured and some widgets are partially visible.

I am trying to find the visibility state of all types of widgets ( obscured, completely visible , partially visible) .
I am using following code snippet.

```
void MainWidget::printVisibilityState()
{
    QList<ChildWidget *> childWidgetsList = findChildren<ChildWidget *>();

    for (register int i = 0;  i  < childWidgetsList.size();  i++)
    {
        ChildWidget* pWidget = childWidgetsList.at(i);

        QRegion visibleRegion = pWidget->visibleRegion();
        QRect visibleRegionBoundingRect = visibleRegion.boundingRect();
        int visibleRegionRectsCount = visibleRegion.rects().count();
        QRect widgetRect = pWidget->rect();

        if (visibleRegion.isEmpty()) {
            qDebug() <<pWidget->getName()<< "is OBSCURED";
        }
        else {
            if (
                (visibleRegionBoundingRect == widgetRect) && 
                    (1 == visibleRegionRectsCount)) 
            {
                qDebug() <<pWidget->getName()<< "is VISIBLE";
            }
            else 
            {
                qDebug() <<pWidget->getName()<< "is PARTIALLY VISIBLE";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I have implemented painEvent in both MainWidget and ChildWidget with the following code snippet.

```
void ChildWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
 {
     QStyleOption opt;
     opt.init(this);
     QPainter p(this);
     style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
 }

void MainWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
 {
     QStyleOption opt;
     opt.init(this);
     QPainter p(this);
     style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
 }
```

This code prints the visibility state for all child widgets as VISIBLE always.

Note: Instead of setting the background-color using style sheet, if I use the setAutoFillBackground(true) for both MainWidget and ChildWidget then I am getting the proper visibility state.

Could you please guide me why it doesn't get me the proper visibility state when used style sheet?
Am I missing something in calculating the visibility state?

Are there any other way to get the visibility state info?

The QWidget document (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#visible-prop) says that, "A widget that happens to be obscured by other windows on the screen is considered to be visible."

If this is the case How do we determine the visibility state for the partially visible widgets? ( For example an error popup on other window, so error popup is completely visible and window is partially visible)

Please help me

Regards

SRaju